# How can I terminate multiprocessing by itself

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Can I stop multiprocessing process by itself ?

when I catch the exception , I want to terminate at exception area.(`doSomething function`)

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Timer

class TTT(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # must call this before anything else
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            t = Timer(5, self.doSomething)
            t.start()
            t.join()

    def doSomething(self):
        try:
            raise Exception('a','b')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # I want to terminate process here~

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    t = TTT('aaa')
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean solution is to put a flag in your `TTT` object:

```
class TTT(multiprocessing.Process):
    ...
    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            t = Timer(5, self.doSomething)
            t.start()
            t.join()

    def doSomething(self):
        try:
            raise Exception('a','b')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.running = False
```

Non-clean solution is to simply `sys.exit(1)` in your exception handler. It is not clean because now your `doSomething` function becomes the master of the process. What if something else needs cleaning up? Don't do that. I'm putting it here just for academic purposes.

Comment: More than a non-clean solution this seems just brutal

Comment: why I can't use `self.terminate()` in except ?

Comment: @RelaxZeroC One reason is that you simply can't use `.terminate()` inside the subprocess - it is intended for the parent process to control its child. And another reason is exactly the same as with `sys.exit`: you don't want some random method to control entire process.

Answer (score 0):

Have an Event to break out of the loop. It is the same thing as a Boolean flag, but it can be used across processes and threads.

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Timer

class TTT(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # must call this before anything else
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.alive = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.alive.set()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive.is_set():
            t = Timer(5, self.doSomething)
            t.start()
            t.join()

    def doSomething(self):
        try:
            raise Exception('a','b')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # I want to terminate process here~
            self.alive.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    t = TTT('aaa')
    t.start()
    t.join()
```